# How to combine text and geo query using Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

As per Mongodb documentation `"Queries cannot use both text and Geospatial Indexes"` means we can't use both `$textSearch` and `$nearSphere` in a Single Spring Data Mongo repository method.

But I am looking for some workaround which will allow me to use both `TextCriteria` and `nearSphere Pint` to be used together, I don't have another way, I am really trying to make this working.

I found the https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/pzlYGKMYMVQ/O6P5S578Xx0J which says that he able to perform some work-around, but I am not getting how he write Repository method for following query ?

```
find({"add.loc": {$near:{$geometry: {type: "Point",coordinates: 
[116.425, -31.09]}, $maxDistance: 500000}},$text:{$search: "hello"}}
```

I am in a worst situation

For my repository method it gives:

```
Page<User> getAddress_PositionNear(TextCriteria tc,Point gpoint, Distance d, Pageable p);

"errmsg" : "text and geoNear not allowed in same query" , "code" : 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combining 2 special index structures in one query is (at the time of writing) **not** possible using MongoDB. This means that a text index cannot be used together with a geospatial index.
[$near](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) requires to operate on a 2d or 2dsphere index and therefore cannot be combined with text search.

However it is possible to use [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) which does not require a geospatial index. Use a `Polygon` or `Circle` for that to construct queries like

```js
db.text_and_geo.find({
     "loc": { "$geoWithin" : { "$geometry": { "type" : "Polygon" , "coordinates": [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ] }}},
     "$text" : { "$search" : "spring"}
})

db.text_and_geo.find({
     "loc": { "$geoWithin": { "$center": [ [1, 1], 10 ] } } ,
     "$text" : { "$search" : "spring"}
})
```

Pretty much the same can be done via `MongoTemplate`

```java
Query queryWithPolygon = TextQuery.queryText(TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage()
  .matching("spring"))
  .addCriteria(
    where("loc")
      .within(new GeoJsonPolygon(new Point(0, 0), new Point(3, 6), new Point(6, 1), new Point(0, 0)));
List<TextAndGeo> result = template.find(queryWithPolygon, TextAndGeo.class);

Query queryWithCircle = TextQuery.queryText(TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage()
  .matching("spring"))
  .addCriteria(
    where("loc")
      .within(new Circle(new Point(0, 0), 10));
List<TextAndGeo> result = template.find(queryWithCircle, TextAndGeo.class);
```

Working with a `Repository` simply use the `Within` keyword for your derived query

```java
Page<TextAndGeo> findByLocWithin(Circle circle, TextCriteria tc, Pageable page)
```

Comment: I am not able to use where("loc"), The method where(String) is undefined for the type classname

Comment: This is the only option to achieve the goal. However, once we start using "within", the results are no longer sorted by distance. Advantage of "near" is the results are sorted by distance. Is there any way to sort the results when we use "within" ?

Comment: Christoph Strobl - Could you please guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185175/invalid-parameter-index-you-seem-to-have-declare-too-little-query-method-parame ?